# Optimization problem length of cable

Tags: calculus

Here is the problem : I have to find the minimum length of cable that I have to use to connect the antenna ( antenna on the picture) to the points $A,B,C$ and $D$:

[image]

I found this relationship :

$$D_1+ D_2 = \sqrt{2^2 + X^2} + \sqrt{(12-x)^2+1^2}$$

But I don't know how I can express the length of cable that connect the points $A$ and $B$ to the antenna. The antenna has to be on the same axis as point $A$ and But its place can be between $A$ and $B$ or behind $B$ or behind $A$...
If someone has an idea....
Sorry for the mistake in english..I'm from france

Comment: The teacher said that all needed information are there...

Comment: Is $x$ the distance along the highway to the antenna from the point on the highway closest to $C$? What are the red $1$ and red $2$? It doesn't look like we are told the positions of points $A$ and $B$ (except that they are $5$km apart and on the highway)

Comment: Also does each point have to be directly connected to the antenna, or can we do connect the points to the antenna in any way we like (e.g. from $C$ through $A$ to the antenna)?

Comment: I think the requirement to connect the antenna to the four points would be satisfied by running cables from the antenna to $A$ and $B$, from $A$ to $C$, and from $B$ to $D$, rather than running separate cables directly to $C$ and $D$ from the antenna. This uses less cable. But the exact amount of cable is still unknown because we don't know how far it is from $A$ to $C$. If you are allowed to "slide" the locations of the points up and down (keeping the marked distances equal) then the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

There were probably some words that went along with the problem that might
give some clues, but since this is a calculus optimization problem I assume
that where the relative positions of the points in the diagram are not
specified, they can be changed in order to reduce the amount of cable used.
That is, you are allowed to put $A$ and $B$ wherever you like as long
as they are $5$ km apart. In particular you can always arrange them
so that the antenna is between $A$ and $B$.

The other consideration is whether you need to run four separate cables
from the antenna to each of the four points, or whether it is enough
to run one cable from the antenna to $A$ and then to $C$ and another
cable from the antenna to $B$ and then to $D$. If you are allowed to
connect the network that way (antenna to $A$, $A$ to $C$, etc.)
then the exact placement of the antenna is not so important (it does not have
to be on the straight line between $C$ and $D$) but the exact placement
of $A$ and $B$ becomes important.

Answer (score 0):

In red, It's me that I draw line to have 2 triangle (triangle 1 and triangle 2)
We are allowed to put A and B wherever we like as long as they are 5 km apart but they have to be on the same line like the picture.
 We can use for cable, the only condition that we have to respect is to use less cable ass possible.
I think I can write this relationship :

D(aA) + D(aB) >=5 I think  (with a is the antenna and A B are the points and D for distance).
But my problem is I don't know how to express DaA and DaB with respect to x...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the original picture :

[image]